# Porque mi prevista de impresion esta en blanco?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de imprimir mi vista con `window.print()` pero cuando presiono el botón me aparece en blanco la vista que se va a imprimir.

Paso a mostrarles la simple función en `JS`:

```
<script>
    function ImprimirPagina() {
        window.print('');
    }
</script>
```

Y este es mi `html`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Main row -->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Left col -->
        <section class="col-md-12">
            <!-- Custom tabs (Charts with tabs)-->
            <div class="card" style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="font-weight-light text-white">Productos
                        <a class="btn bg-white float-right btn-sm" href="{{ route('products.add') }}">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                            Agregar Producto
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- /.card-header -->
            <div>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-responsive" width="100%">
                    <thead class="thead">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="display: none">Codigo</th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Producto</th>
                            <th>Tipo de Producto</th>
                            <th>Marca</th>
                            <th>Modelo</th>
                            <th>Moneda de Compra</th>                                                                       
                            <th>Costo Fob</th>
                            <th>Moneda de Venta</th>
                            <th>Precio de Lista</th>
                            <th>Margen Bruto</th>
                            <th style="width: 12%">Accion</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($file as $key => $product)
                            @if($product->status == 1)
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="display: none">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->marca->brandName . " " . $product->modelo->modelName }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product['ptype']['productType'] }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->marca->brandName }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->modelo->modelName }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->coin }}</td>                                    
                                    <td>{{ $product->costUSD }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->sale_coin }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->list_priceUSD }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->marginUSD }}</td>

                                    @php
                                        $count_product = App\Model\Purchase::where('product_id',$product->id)->count();
                                    @endphp

                                    <td>
                                        <!--<a title="Download" id="download" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="/products/download/{{ $product->file }}">
                                            <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
                                        </a>-->
                                        <a title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm text-white" style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);" href="{{ route('products.edit', $product->id) }}">
                                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a title="Delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{{ route('products.delete', $product->id) }}">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a title="Info" id="info" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{{ route('products.detail', $product->id) }}" >
                                            <i class="fa fa-eye" ></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->

            <button onclick="ImprimirPagina();" class="btn btn-success">
                <i class="fas fa-print"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ahora no se porque cuando toco en el botón de imprimir lo único que se ve es lo siguiente:

[image: Se encuentra la vista en blanco en vez de mostrar el datatable y sus datos]

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer estás usando Bootstrap 3, el cuál tiene algunos [problemas conocidos](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/#support-printing) a la hora de imprimir. Puedes intentar con lo siguiente en CSS:

```css
@media print {
  .container-fluid {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

Tambien puedes usar `window.frame` para imprimir solo los nodos del HTML que necesites, evitando así el que tiene la clase `.container-fluid`.